# What is the cheapest way to do writes, versions, and diffs in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

I'm currently using DynamoDb to store a JSON Object, then when there is an update to the object, compare it against what is in DynamoDB, then update what is in DDB, and return the old and new version as a diff.

I ran into an issue where the object was too large for DDB, so I'm looking at needing to store it in S3 and maybe store a file path in DDB and when I do the diff, pull the file down and compare it with what I have and send the diff along. Then I got to thinking about the fact that S3 has versions and I could compare versions, but my biggest concern is cost at scale. I found an article talking about how anything over 20K is cheaper to write/access in S3 than in DDB, but below that, DDB is cheaper. Most of my objects are 5-10K, so it seems most of the time, DDB is cheaper. But that also got me thinking, is there a better cost solution for running a diff between what I currently have and what existed? I don't really need to have a bunch of versions hanging around, I just need the current and previous versions.

Comment: Does the diff need to be returned synchronously, or can it be sent as an asynchronous message?

Comment: Where are you getting pricing information that suggests that DynamoDB is cheaper than S3? DynamoDB is $0.25 per GB-month (for storage) and S3 is less than 1/10th of that, for example. S3 has zero costs for writes, while DynamoDB charges for write requests (not much, but a non-zero cost).

Comment: @JasonWadsworth I can handle either one, so that wouldn't be an issue, it would just have to have a pretty high throughput. I'll post what my DDB read/write is at right now (autoscaled).

Comment: @jarmod https://www.cirrusup.cloud/s3-vs-dynamodb-price-comparison/ I'll check the cost explorer to see how things shake up for my read/write throughput.

Comment: Currently using about 3k write capacity (on average for the last 2 weeks), and 1. Not really doing any reads because of using change stream.

Comment: Indeed I got a very different number. The DDB Calculator I put in 33GB for dataset storage (the current size for the table after ~3 months). 5k item size (provisioned). 1000 writes/second. 10GB data transfer in/month. Cost came to $2,606. The table is currently telling me $2.4k, so that's pretty close.

Comment: S3, Storage: 60GB (it would be 2-3x because of versions), PUT/etc… requests: 2000000, Get/Etc… requests: 2000000. Data returned 10GB. Data scanned 10GB. Monthly bill: $12.76. Is that really correct? and can S3 handle that many items?

Comment: I think you're asking if S3 can handle your request rate rather than if it can handle that many items (because, yes it can handle that many items, whatever number that turns out to be). Your DDB calculations appear to be based on writing 1000 items, each 5KB in size, per second. Is that genuinely your requirement?

Comment: Yes. And I think I got my answer from more research. S3 can handle up to 55,000 items per second per bucket. So that should be at least 13x what I actually need. I'm going to try it on a small scale item, then run it parallel to DDB to see if it can handle the load, and if all goes well, maybe save several $k/month!

Comment: Bah! If I knew how to use the AWS calculator, I wouldn't have come up with the $12 conclusion. Looks like S3 would cost roughly 2x what DDB is currently costing.

Answer (score 0):

I would employ the below scheme

```
id    |  hashid      | docPath        | doc(where ever size is<400kb)
123   |  456         | bucket1/123    | {"a":"b"}
122   |  789         | bucket1/122    |
```

when a write request for doc 123 comes,

1. get row from table with id=123
2. Check if hashid of existing doc and new doc are same
3. if no then old and new doc are same so no need to change anything.
4. if yes

   a.  if doc is present in table response

   - return the doc as existing doc

   b. else

   - get the doc from s3 using docpath and return the doc as existing doc

   if the new doc size< 400kb write this to both Dynamodb and s3, else write to s3 and just update the metadata in dynamodb. and store the s3 path in Dynamodb table.

This will make sure

1. For most of the use cases(wherever doc fits in Dynamodb) you will be doing only 1 read and write to dynamodb, and they would be extremely fast.
2. For other use cases (where doc could not fit in Dynamodb table) you will be doing 2 read write from dynamodb and s3. only when it is required (i.e. docs are actually different).
3. You have s3 for history of every doc.